# Phaser 3: load spritesheet for animation with unequal dimensions

Tags: javascript, sprite, phaser-framework, sprite-sheet

Im trying to work with the phaser 3 framework.

In order to load a spritesheet and create its animation I first load the spritesheet:

`this.load.spritesheet('player', 'assets/spritesheets/player.png',{frameWidth:16,frameheight:16});`

then I create the animation as follows:

```
this.anims.create({
    key:"player_anim",
    frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers("player"),
    frameRate:8,
    repeat:-1,
});
```

This works fine but if I have unequal dimensions such as

```
this.load.spritesheet('1health', 'assets/spritesheets/1health.png',{frameWidth:96,frameheight:32});

this.anims.create({
    key:"1health_anim",
    frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers("1health"),
    frameRate:4,
    repeat:-1,
});
```

I receive the following error:

```
SpriteSheet frame dimensions will result in zero frames for texture: 1health

generateFrameNumbers: Frame 0 missing from texture: 1health
generateFrameNumbers: Frame 0 missing from texture: 1health
```

if i print `console.log(this.anims.generateFrameNumbers("player"));`

the output is:

```
[
    {
        "key": "player",
        "frame": 0
    },
    {
        "key": "player",
        "frame": 1
    },
    {
        "key": "player",
        "frame": 2
    },
    {
        "key": "player",
        "frame": 3
    }
]
```

however for the unequal dimension sprite I get an empty array.

In [Phaser's Documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Loader.LoaderPlugin.html) it seems to be okay to use different dimensions for a spritesheet.

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

**Edit**
Here are thee images I tried using

[image: 1health.png]

[image: 1health.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything works fine for me, here is how I display a sprite in a scene:

In `loading.js`:

```js
this.load.spritesheet('6bQOE', 'img/6bQOE.png', {frameWidth: 96, frameHeight: 32});
```

Gameplay:

```
let animConfig = {
    key: "gameAnim",
    frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers("6bQOE", { frames: [ 0,1,2 ] }),
    frameRate: 12,
    repeat: -1,
};
this.anims.create(animConfig);
this.gameAnimation = this.anims.create(config);

// display the sprite
this.anim = this.add.sprite(width/2 + 400, height/2+5, '6bQOE');
this.anim.anims.play("gameAnim");
```

[image]

But you have two exactly same frames, so I don't understand what you are trying to do? Switching between those frames does not make any difference, there is always one red and two black hearts.

Maybe you don't need any animation, you can set frame using:

```
this.anim.setFrame(0); // 3 red hearts
this.anim.setFrame(1); // 2 red hearts
```

Comment: Thank you, I added the spritesheets I used in the question (In the first one I put them next to each other and the other one I put the on top of each other; I used a software called piskel to create them). Also trying dimensions of 94 by 30 also did not work, but If i use 32x32 it works but of course results in an undesirable sprite animation.

Comment: @A.JAlhorr I have edited my answer, but to be honest I don't understand what you trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you it works, so I was missing the additional parameter for the `generateFrameNumbers` function. Also the two frames are very slightly different (I'm not very good at art :/ ); I was going for the light and shadow of the heart to be moving and little "blood" pixels dropping from the black heart. Don't worry Im just getting familiar with the phaser framework, and won't be handling the art in whatever my company decides to do...